# After running Ajax to change the order of a table, my other jQuery functions on the table returned are not executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using Ajax to change the order of a table when the user clicks on the headings in the first row of the table. The second function executes before the order of any column is changed however, after the user has clicked on a heading, and then clicks on a cell in either of the last two columns there is no alert. I am returning a table from PHP with the same ids and classes as the initial table, therefore I am unsure as to why the jQuery function is not recognising the click.

```
$(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function () {
    var column_name = $(this).attr("id");
    var order = $(this).data("order");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../table.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {column_name: column_name, order: order},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#populate_table').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('table .row td:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(5)').click(function () {
    var vote_up = $(this).parent().index();
    alert(vote_up); // this works before Ajax. Does not work after
});
```

Here is the php which interacts with the above Ajax to query my database and change the order of the columns.

```
<?php

include 'database.php'; // include database connection file
$output = '';
$order = $_POST["order"];
if ($order == 'desc') {
    $order = 'asc';
} else {
    $order = 'desc';
}
$query = "SELECT user, gender, description, up_votes, down_votes FROM 
table_name ORDER BY " . $_POST["column_name"] . " " . $_POST["order"] . " ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$output .= '  
 <table>
      <tr class="row">
           <td><a class="column_sort" id="user" data-order="' . $order . '" href="#" onclick="return false;">User</a></td>  
           <td><a class="column_sort" id="gender" data-order="' . $order . '" href="#" onclick="return false;">Gender</a></td>
           <td><a class="column_sort" id="description" data-order="' . $order . '" href="#" onclick="return false;">Description</a></td>
           <td><a class="column_sort" id="up_votes" data-order="' . $order . '" href="#" onclick="return false;"><img class="vote" src="Gender/images/table/up.png" alt="up-vote"></a></td>  
           <td><a class="column_sort" id="down_votes" data-order="' . $order . '" href="#" onclick="return false;"><img class="vote" src="Gender/images/table/down.png" alt="down-vote"></a></td>  
      </tr>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '  
          <tr class="row">
               <td>' . $row["user"] . '</td>
               <td>' . $row["gender"] . '</td>
               <td>' . $row["description"] . '</td>
               <td>' . $row["up_votes"] . '</td>
               <td>' . $row["down_votes"] . '</td></tr>';
    }
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;

?>
```

And finally here is the HTML.

```
<div id="populate_table">
    <table>  
        <tr class="row">  
            <td><a class="column_sort" id="user" data-order="desc" href="#" onclick="return false;">User</a></td>
            <td><a class="column_sort" id="gender" data order="desc" href="#" onclick="return false;">Gender</a></td>
            <td><a class="column_sort" id="description" data order="desc" href="#" onclick="return false;">Description</a></td>
            <td><a class="column_sort" id="up_votes" data order="desc" href="#" onclick="return false;"><img class="vote" src="Gender/images/table/up.png" alt="up-vote"></a></td>
            <td><a class="column_sort" id="down_votes" data order="desc" href="#" onclick="return false;"><img class="vote" src="Gender/images/table/down.png" alt="down-vote"></a></td>
        </tr>  
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <tr class="row">  
                <td><?php echo $row["user"]; ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row["gender"]; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row["up_votes"]; ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row["down_votes"]; ?></td>  
            </tr>  
            <?php
        }
        ?>  
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When you replace the table content, all event handlers formerly bound to former elements are lost. You can overcome that problem by using event delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change .click(...) with:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'table .row td:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(5)', function() {
     ...
});
```